# Aligning two graphs(Pie and Bar) side by side :: d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am a little new to D3 js.I need to align two graphs (bar and pie) side by side which will be displayed on a dashboard.When I use individual .html files for bar and pie charts,they work perfectly but the charts are getting overlapped when I combine them into a single .html file.

I have tried changing different parameters related to "svg" and corresponding x and y axes but to no avail.

There are two csv files(pie-data.csv,bar-data.csv) from where data will be picked.

Below is my code ::

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.arc text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 40)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.ticket_count; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

d3.csv("pie-data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.ticket_meter); });

  g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.ticket_meter; });
});

function type(d) {
  d.ticket_count = +d.ticket_count;
  return d;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 150 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("bar-data.csv", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.issue_status = d.issue_status;
        d.issue_count = +d.issue_count;
    });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.issue_status; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.issue_count; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")



  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")

      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.issue_status); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.issue_count); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.issue_count); });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest any pointers so that alignment can be done.Thanks in advance.

Comment: so many duplicate variable names  -.-

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable twice:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
```

(and, besides that one, you are repeating some other variables that should be unique)

Appending the SVGs to the "body" is not the correct way, because when you append an SVG to the body the SVG is put at the end of the page, and you'll not be able to position them side by side.

A solution would be creating one div for each chart, with IDs #chart1 and #chart2 for instance, and then creating two variables:

```
var svg1 = d3.select("#chart1").append("svg");
```

And

```
var svg2 = d3.select("#chart2").append("svg");
```

Don't forget to change all other variables accordingly.

After the changes, use CSS to align the two divs side by side.